# Multi-layer reverse proxy - Nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, http-proxy

In my web application architecture, I would like to separate the **application layer** from the **authentication/authorization layer**.

My initial idea would be this:

[image]

Some **requirements** of this **system**:

- I need to **authenticate** the user by **generating** and **validating** JWT tokens
- It would be interesting to **store** them for revocation
- Additionally, I need to have a **specific authorization** system, such as **quota system** and **allowed modules**

That said, from what I understand, it would be impractical to just use NGinx, and not an intermediary server/service.

Nginx provides some features, but to me it seems insufficient for the whole purpose:
[Setting up JWT Authentication](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-jwt-authentication/), [Authentication Based on Subrequest Result](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/)

Following the image, the **flow** would be:

- Client accesses Nginx
- Nginx forwards the entire request to an intermediate server/service that must perform validations and return the original request, possibly modified.
- If the intermediary server returns success to Nginx, Nginx must forward the request to the application server/service
- The application service returns the response to the client.

I believe this is a common architecture, but what are the best practices and ideal tools to use? Is it possible with NGinx? As?

```
App Server: PHP
Auth Server: any
```